# Reverse polarity protection and inrush current limiting - back to back mosfets

Tags: mosfet, ltspice, simulation, protection, reverse-polarity

I was testing this circuit in LTspice, it would protect my boards from reverse polarity and limit the inrush current to the input capacitor of a DC-DC (buck or LDO),

[image]

but the simulation gave me this results and I don't understand what's happening.

[image]
[image]

The first MOSFET should do the inrush current limiting function, the second the reverse voltage protection.  I tested also the "inverted version", first and second MOSFET inverted function, but the same thing happens.

Where does that -200 A current come from?

Shouldn't the circuit block the reverse current?

Comment: When the pulse ends at 1.3s, V1 becomes a dead short across the input. Both MOSFETs remain full on, since there isn't time for their gate-source capacitance (and C2) to discharge. The -240 A pulse is the discharge current of C1 through the MOSFETs.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But can i solve it somehow?

Comment: Solve what? Are you saying that in your application, it's likely that the input will be shorted before C1 can discharge, and that you need to limit the current for that case? In most applications, the input becomes open-circuit when the power is removed. Your V1 is not a good simulation model for that. Maybe put an ideal diode in series with it?

Comment: You're right, i'm sorry. Thank you. Another question if I may. Is there a limit to the capacity C that I can put C2?

Answer (score 1):

These MOSFETS will be all the time ON since you need 0V between Gate and Source (0 Vgs) (not higher than -0.6V according to the datasheet) to turn them OFF. Which means, in this case, that
the gate should be at 24V relative to ground (assuming 24VDC supply). The Zener diodes, by definition, will never bring the gate at this level.
Rising the supply voltage will not drive the gate closer to 0 Vgs. But always at Vsupply - Vzener.

The short spike is caused by the capacitor very shortly driving the gate at 0Vgs.